# DatePicker stopping CoreData working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, uidatepicker

I have an app which saves text and the date from a UIDatePicker and then shows that note if you got back into that date in the UIDatePicker.

It works great! Only I have found that setting the UIDatePicker date to today stops CoreData working.

It's only when I run this setDate line does it stop core data from working. The app runs fine without crashing, it just doesn't save any data. If I comment that line out, it works a charm. But I need to have the UIDatePicker on today when the app loads.

I use this when the application starts:

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[datePicker setDate:now];
```

This to fetch the note:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *testEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DatedText" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetch setEntity:testEntity];
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateSaved == %@", datePicker.date];
        [fetch setPredicate:pred];
        
        NSError *fetchError = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjs = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
        if (fetchError != nil) {
            NSLog(@"fetchError = %@, details = %@",fetchError,fetchError.userInfo);
        }
        noteTextView.text = [[fetchedObjs objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"savedText"];
```

And this to save the note:

```
NSManagedObject *newDatedText;
    newDatedText = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DatedText" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [newDatedText setValue:noteTextView.text forKey:@"savedText"];
    [newDatedText setValue:datePicker.date forKey:@"dateSaved"];
    
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];
    if (saveError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"[%@ saveContext] Error saving context: Error = %@, details = %@",[self class], saveError,saveError.userInfo);
    }
```

Comment: The last few lines of code you posted show that the -save: method will pass back an error if it can't save. Are you seeing an error? If so, *what is it*? If no error, how are you sure it's not saving anything? How *exactly* are you verifying this? Also, your first block of code at app startup appears to leak an NSDate instance. You alloc/init without releasing it. Try [NSDate date] to return an autoreleased instance or release it after you're done with it (after you hand it to the date picker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember NSDate saves not only DD/MM/YYYY but also HH:MM:SS.

At a guess I think when you pick a DD/MM/YYYY from the picker, it saves with a default time of 0:00:00 but in the case above when you set the picker date to now you are actually manipulating the HH:MM:SS to something else (even though you don't see it manually).

To illustrate what I'm trying to say, when you fetch is with a predicate of (dateSaved == picker.date) it is looking for a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00 and for arguments sake you may have saved it on DD/MM/YYYY 09:00:01.

You will need to do some formatting of your NSDate attribute if you want this to work.

Comment: So I need to format so I get make some kind of NSDateFormatter with a format of DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00, but some how keeping the time at zero?

Comment: How would I make an NSDate while forcing the time to zero? Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is by default set to todays date only. You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: No it doesn't. I have one in Interface Builder and it has a actual property in the inspector where you set the date and time it starts on. No automatic today's date option sadly.

Comment: To quote Apple docs: "The default is the date when the UIDatePicker object is created." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html